# Global Picklist Defaults in Winter '18 release

Tags: winter18

In my winter '18 release preview sandbox (cs11), picklist fields referencing global value sets no longer populate the default defined in the global value set on record create. Record type defaults and default overrides still work. Has anyone else experienced this?

I did see this known issue but it looks like the opposite of my issue: 
Record Type Default isn't honored when multiple fields use the same global value set in Classic

Comment: This is an issue when apex inserts records or when manually creating records in both lightning and classic UI.